# How to create domain class for rest api in spring if output json has a key with dot(.) character

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, jackson

I am consuming a rest API in Spring Boot but I am getting this error -

```
   java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
```

On rigorous debugging, I found it was because my domain class does not have a key that I am getting in API response *"developer.email"*.

I have `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` annotation in the domain class.
Java does not let you create a variable name with "developer.email"

How do I make it work? Is there a workaround in spring framework for such cases?
Is there a way to manually configure this entity instead of spring autoconfigure.

This is the JSON that I am trying to parse

```
 {"developer.email" : "dev.accounts+developerapps@domain.com"}
```

This is my current domain class, I am using lombok here.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Data
public class OauthTokenResponse {
    private String refresh_token_expires_in;
    private String refresh_token_status;
    private String api_product_list;
    private String app_enduser;
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<String> api_product_list_json;
    private String organization_name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonProperty("developer.email")
    private String developerEmail;

    private String token_type;
    private String issued_at;
    private String client_id;
    private String access_token;
    private String refresh_token;
    private String application_name;
    private String scope;
    private String refresh_token_issued_at;
    private String expires_in;
    private String refresh_count;
    private String status;
}
```

Comment: please show your domain class where you have use annotation.

Comment: @RahulGupta I have updated the domain class in my question

Comment: i updated my answer.please have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try annotating the field with '@JsonProperty' ?

```
@JsonProperty("developer.email")
String developerEmail
```

Small test to prove my point:

```
public class Evil {
  @JsonProperty("evil.property")
  public int evil;
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MapperTest {
  @Test
  public void mapperTest() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final String test = "{ \"evil.property\" : 2 }";
    final Evil evil = mapper.readValue(test, Evil.class);
    assertThat(evil.evil, is(2));
  }
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same exception. Is there a way to ignore this key?

Comment: remove the  @JsonIgnore from the property - do not ignore and map it at once :) i wrote a small unit tests and it works fine with "evil.properties.with.dots"

Comment: I will try this next time

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to ignore this key?

You can use `@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "developer.email")` annotation to ignore this property.

Comment: already using this, but something else is the problem. I think I am going the wrong way

Comment: And also use @JsonIgnore in getter of developerEmail property.Check and plesae let me know it is working or not.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but this is not working I have found a workaround to this.

Comment: Getting response in a string and then parsing it to a MongoDB Document